# R: filter without the implied weight of 1 on current value

Tags: r

The R function `filter` accepts as arguments a vector `x` and a filter `f`, and performs the computation

> y[i] = x[i] + f[1]*y[i-1] + … + f[p]*y[i-p]

However, there is an implied coefficient of 1 on the lag 0 term in the filter -- quoting from the man page for `filter`:

> Note that there is an implied coefficient 1 at lag 0 in the recursive
>   filter

Is there a way in filter to override this default? What is the best way to produce the filter

> y[i] = f[0]*x[i] + f[1]*y[i-1] + … + f[p]*y[i-p]

I would like to avoid loops as far as possible. My current thought is to use something like `Reduce` or `Filter`, but a canned C solution would be preferred.

Comment: Please provide a small example vector and the expected outcome.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Thanks for your interest in this query. I have actually arrived at a solution using `Reduce` and will post that as an answer together with a MWE in a bit.